# Degree of the hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580753/the-relationship-between-hilbert-polynomial-and-the-degree-of-the-variety) question, it is discussed that “if the dimension of projective variety $X$ is $n$ and $p_X(m)$ is its Hilbert polynomial, then leading term of $p_X$ is $\dfrac{\deg{X}}{n!}m^n$.”

I might be asking an obvious question, excuse my ignorance, but how do we know that degree of $p_X$ is also $n$?

Comment: The linked question shows it is at least $n$ Hirzebruch-Rieman-Roch shows it is at most $n$.

Comment: Typically the existence theorem for hilbert polynomials of projective varieties includes this fact. [These notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~eclader/HilbertPolynomials.pdf) for example include the fact that the $\dim(X)$ is equal to the degree of $p_X$. This is because the induction step always relies on what's called Lemma 3 in those notes, which uses the degree of the polynomial.